# Yii Number Formatting

Tags: php, yii

Im trying to format my cgridview column to display numbers with 2 decimal places.

Example 9137 should display as 91.37 not 9137.00

Is there a simple way to do this with PHP or Yii?

Comment: Divide the data by 100 before displaying them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the specific column as an associative array of two properties: `name` as its name and `value` as the *expression* that is applied to get the result. Then modify this expression accordingly: the number should be divided by 100, then formatted. For example:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns'      => array(
        'cost',          // display the 'cost' attribute
        array(           // display the 'cost_in_dollars' using an expression
            'name'  =>  'cost_in_dollars',
            'value' =>  'number_format($data->cost/100, 2)',
        ),
    ),
));
```