# Decimal Format in Yii TBGridview

Tags: php, yii, cgridview

I have code like this :

```
<?php 
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView',array(
'id'=>'appliances-grid',
'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
'filter'=>$model,
'columns'=>array(
        array(
            'name'=>'price',
            'type'=>'number',
            'htmlOptions'=>array('style' => 'text-align: right;'),
        ),
        array(
            'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonColumn',
            'template'=>'{update}{delete}'
        ),
    ),
)); 
?>
```

the result is integer number only and search filter is work, how to change it into decimal format but search filter still working ? 
I tried to change it into :

```
array(
    'name'=>'price',
    'type'=>'number',
    'htmlOptions'=>array('style' => 'text-align: right;'),
    'value'=>function($data)
             {
                return number_format($data->price,2,',','.');
             },
),
```

But it makes search filter not working properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answers here :

1. [Yii Number Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20052881/yii-number-formatting)
2. [How to format numeric string using C.Gridview - Yii](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24936831/how-to-format-numeric-string-using-c-gridview-yii)

And also I found this link [Yii , show different date format in cgridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11052332/yii-show-different-date-format-in-cgridview)

Answer (score 0):

```
Try This:-  
  $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'columns'      => array(
            'cost',          // display the 'cost' attribute
            array(           // display the 'cost_in_dollars' using an expression
                'name'  =>  'cost_in_dollars',
                'value' =>  'number_format($data->cost/100, 2)',
            ),
        ),
    ));
```